# Can someone help me figure out why it keeps saying that largest is undefined? Smallest runs fine

Tags: python

```
firstNumber = -50;
secondNumber = 53;
thirdNumber = 78;

# Write assignment, if, or if else statements here as appropriate
if secondNumber>firstNumber:
    if secondNumber>thirdNumber:
        largest=secondNumber
elif firstNumber>secondNumber:
    if firstNumber>thirdNumber:
        largest=firstNumber
else:
    largest=thirdNumber
if secondNumber<firstNumber:
    if secondNumber<thirdNumber:
        smallest=secondNumber
elif firstNumber<secondNumber:
    if firstNumber<thirdNumber:
        smallest=firstNumber
else:
    smallest=thirdNumber

# Output largest and smallest number. 
print("The largest value is " + str(largest))
print("The smallest value is " + str(smallest))
```

Can someone help me figure out why it keeps saying that largest is undefined? Smallest runs fine
I've been sitting here for the past 30 minutes trying to see if I typed largest wrong lol

Answer (score 1):

largest is undefined because there's no condition where largest is created.  see the comments I added for additional insight.

```
firstNumber = -50
secondNumber = 53
thirdNumber = 78

# Write assignment, if, or if else statements here as appropriate
if secondNumber>firstNumber: # is True
    if secondNumber>thirdNumber: # is False
        largest=secondNumber
elif firstNumber>secondNumber: # Skipped because first if is True
    if firstNumber>thirdNumber:
        largest=firstNumber
else: # Skipped because first if is True
    largest=thirdNumber
if secondNumber<firstNumber:
    if secondNumber<thirdNumber:
        smallest=secondNumber
elif firstNumber<secondNumber:
    if firstNumber<thirdNumber:
        smallest=firstNumber
else:
    smallest=thirdNumber

# Output largest and smallest number. 
print("The largest value is " + str(largest))
print("The smallest value is " + str(smallest))
```

if you remove the nesting, it will work

```
# Write assignment, if, or if else statements here as appropriate
if secondNumber>firstNumber and secondNumber>thirdNumber:
        largest=secondNumber
elif firstNumber>secondNumber and firstNumber>thirdNumber:
        largest=firstNumber
else: 
    largest=thirdNumber
if secondNumber<firstNumber and secondNumber<thirdNumber:
        smallest=secondNumber
elif firstNumber<secondNumber and firstNumber<thirdNumber:
        smallest=firstNumber
else:
    smallest=thirdNumber

# Output largest and smallest number. 
print("The largest value is " + str(largest))
print("The smallest value is " + str(smallest))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is subtle. What is happening here is, if one of the top-level *if* statments if true, then the *elif* and *else* statments is automatically being not considered. So in this example, because your second number is larger than your first, **BUT NOT** larger than the second, the code goes down the path of your first *if* statment, but since the second *if* statment within is not true, the variable "largest" actually never gets assigned.

An alternative way is to use a "and" syntax on your if statments e.g.,

```
if secondNumber>firstNumber and secondNumber>thirdNumber: 
    largest = secondNumber
```